# How to detect what Ribbon is currently active in a Microsoft Office application?

Tags: ms-office, autohotkey, ribbon, onenote

I have looked at ActiveControlList but unfortunately it wasn't a reliable way to tell the active ribbon.
Specifically, I am looking for a reliable way to tell if Equation Tools ribbon is active in OneNote.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ribbon is not a normal control and can be hard to work with from plain VBA or ahks built-in COM but you can use Microsoft's Active Accessibility API

You Can use the [Acc lib](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/77303-acc-library-ahk-l-updated-09272012/?hl=%20acc%20%20lib) so you don't need to know all the dll calls

But you still need to know what parts you need, and also what to look for to really use it. You can use jethrows [AccViewer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60539023/AHK%20Forum/AccViewer.exe) it will tell you the elements Role, State, ChildCount and more, so when you have found the item you're after, you can use the Tree or path that the accViewer gives.

Word ribbon path Example: 4.3.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.13.1.1

OneNote: 4.3.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.10.1.1

Here is an **example** using Acc_get() to show the current ribbon Name in OneNote PP 2010 when you press F6

```
f6::
name := Acc_Get("Name", "4.3.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.1.4.10.1.1", 0, "Ahk_class Framework::CFrame")
tooltip % name
return
```

**Note:** that this path is for when the ribbon is pinned i.e always visible

[Forum topic with images](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/119282-autohotkey-accessibility-library-acc-lib-does-not-work-for-office-2013-controls/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no specific commands for Ribbon GUIs.
Use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) to detect changes in Ribbon GUI. You can search with [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) image of activated Equation Tools control and if it finds it, it will set `ErrorLevel` to `1`.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Check out with windowSpy! ?

Comment: I did, I see no difference in windowSpy when different ribbons are active.

Comment: I currently don't have the chance to test it, but what kind of control does the WindowSpy it is?

Comment: @JoeDF I tested Microsoft Office Word 2013 ribbon menu in window spy. There is no difference between controls.

Comment: I'm NOT asking for the difference. What is the ClassNN name or what is the NAME or TYPE of control is it?

Comment: For Winword: when Mouse in on the ribbons, ClassNN: NETUIHWND1 , when mouse is on the document, ClassNN: _WwG1. Mouse must be on the ribbon or document for these names of controls to show up.